# Amazon workspaces - No network : Network connection lost. Check your network connection or contact administrator for

Tags: networking, amazon-workspaces

I'm facing an error while connecting to a Amazon workspace via windows client.

This error shows up as soon as I start up the client, so I'm not even able to register using my registration code or see login page. The error is: 'No network : Network connection lost. Check your network connection or contact administrator for help.' This workspace is not new, it is one which I have been using for more than 2 years with same registration code. The issue is a lot weird, as I'm not sure what is exactly causing it. I tested using following ways:

Primary laptop : laptop1 Secondary laptop : laptop2 Primary network : net1 Secondary network : net2

I get the above error when I use the combination of laptop1 and net1. But when I use the combination of laptop1 and net2, I'm able to access the workspace. This made me think maybe something is being blocked on my net1. But then I tried combination of laptop2 and net1, I was able to access my workspace as expected.

The only thing different on laptop1 and laptop2 is that laptop2 had a fresh install of Amazon workspace client, as it never had the setup done on it previously. The laptop1 being my daily usage one had the amazon workspace installed on it. I tried removing the amazon workspace client form laptop1 with some advanced uninstallers and system temp directories clean up , restart and then re install of the client, but still the issue persisted.

I cannot use laptop2 as my daily one, and have to try to get it working on laptop1 and net1 combo. Also net2 cannot be used continuously as it is a cellular network.

Attached are logs from, please let me know if any more details are required: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Amazon Web Services\Amazon WorkSpaces\logs Logs:

```
Laptop1, network1 https://pastebin.com/raw/hJQqm7JA
Laptop1, network2 https://pastebin.com/raw/U97UHEbh
Laptop2, network1 https://pastebin.com/raw/2ZHrMvPP
```

Screen shots:
Startup
[image: Startup]
Before login
[image: Before login]
Connection
[image: Connection]